# Rails4. Contacts importer from famous providers (Gmail, Facebook...)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, oauth-2.0, import-contacts

**Problem**

Need to implement contacts importer/chooser on Rails4 project. Needed providers - Gmail, Facebook, Yahoo, LinkedIn, Outlook.

**Researches**

Tried [omnicontacts](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts) and [contacts](https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts) gems but both has some limitations and maybe outdated for some providers.

There is commercial project which do this for you - [CloudSponge](https://www.cloudsponge.com) , but I prefer open source.

**Current Status**

Implemented Linkedin contacts import using devise, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin.
Implemented Gmail contacts import using omnicontatcs.
Failed with other providers.

**Queastion**

Is there any other all-in-one solutions (maybe I missed something) which could be useful for my issue or I have to implement all things from scratch, maybe using already outdated gems/libs ?

Another thing I was thinking, maybe this task better to solve on client side using javascript libraries?

Answer (score 3):

If you to try implement contacts importer in a do-it-youself way, the first goal will be proper learn OAuth2 and all the 4 authentication flows. I like [this blog post](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/) explanation.

Then if you want to use a client-side-only solution for OAuth2, you'll need to use the **Implicit** flow.

For Google Contacts, you can find **Implicit** flow documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent).

**Disclaimer**: I work for CloudSponge, and I'm a big fan of free/open-source solutions too. I even use Linux as my desktop :)

Comment: Thanks @Rael. +1 for blog post.